# Subfolder of github pages shows me an old react code instead of a new website

Tags: reactjs, github, sapper

I have an html page in a subfolder of my github page but I don't see it. instead I see an old react app I once had there.

- Site: oren.github.io/food
- Code: https://github.com/oren/oren.github.io/tree/master/food

Any idea what's going there? Maybe some settings on my github pages that I need to tweak? I don't think it's caching issue since it has been 7 hours since I copy the code of my new site into the food folder.

Comment: did you push your commits from your local repo  ?

Answer (score 0):

i deleted both my food repo and my github pages repo and the problem is solved (:

I believe that react did some interesting things with `gh-pages`. anyway. life is great.